# Why is FireSheep such a big deal?

Tags: tools, black-hat

We've had WireShark and other tools for a long time before. Why does everybody make such a big deal about FireSheep?

Comment: Because it got media attention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ingredients of "success": Facebook + conference + FireFox. And sure, as @AviD has said - it is easy, no special knowledge is required. Good gathering of references is on Schneier blog: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2010/10/firesheep.html.

Answer (score 7):

Because it's easy.
And accessible.

Firesheep didn't create any new technology, and noone claims it did. But the point is, it has now become extremely easy to view and spoof others identities, and it is very accessible to almost any user (well, any user that can download and install Firefox and Firesheep plugin...)

It's really just a question of visibility.